# Algebraic Dirichlet series and beyond

Tags: nt.number-theory, generating-functions, functional-equations

I wonder what the "right" notion of "algebraic Dirichlet series" might be. Here I'm thinking of formal Dirichlet series $D(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n/n^s$, say with $a_n$ being rational numbers.

I'm trying to figure out an analogon for the rich class of algebraic formal power series $A(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$, that satisfy a polynomial relation $p(z, A(z))=0$, for some polynomial $p$ with integer coefficients.

The main question is, what should be the replacement of $z$?  A good candidate seems to be $\zeta(s)$, i.e., maybe "algebraic" should mean "satisfying a polynomial equation $p(\zeta(s), D(s))$=0".

More generally, what would an interesting notion of "differentially algebraic Dirichlet series", i.e., is there a good candidate for a replacement of the derivative, that plays nicely together with the replacement for $z$.  It would be particularly nice if this derivative would send $z^k$ to a linear combination of smaller powers of $z$.

Of course, most important are that such dependencies actually occur, so some nice examples beyond those on [wikipedia:Dirichlet series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) would be very, very helpful.

Comment: I just found *Dependence of arithmetic functions and Dirichlet series* by Vichian Laohakosol, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 115 (1992), 637-645, who proves some algebraic independence results of Dirichlet series.  However, he does not give any (non-trivial) examples of algebraic dependencies, unfortunately.